# Improve MySQL query speed with lots of joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, database-performance

I have a query in MySQL which uses multiple joins and it runs slow at the moment - on average it is taking around 35 seconds to run.

The query is:

```
SELECT t.id,
       CASE t.emp_accepted
           WHEN '1' THEN 'No'
           WHEN '0' THEN 'Yes'
       END AS accepted,
       e.department,
       e.works_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.sur_name,
       e.job_title,
       e.job_status,
       e.site_id,
       e.manager,
       d1.department_name AS dept_name,
       d2.department_name AS sub_dept_name,
       temp_hours_worked.hours AS hours,
       s.office_name AS site_name,
       CONCAT(e2.first_name, ' ', e2.sur_name) AS manager_name,
       CONCAT(e3.first_name, ' ', e3.sur_name) AS validated_by
FROM time t
LEFT JOIN employee e
    ON t.employee_id = e.employee_id
LEFT JOIN departments d1
    ON e.department = d1.id
LEFT JOIN departments d2
    ON e.sub_department = d2.id
LEFT JOIN site s
    ON e.site_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN employee e2
    ON e.manager = e2.id
LEFT JOIN employee e3
    ON t.manager_id = e3.id
LEFT JOIN temp_hours_worked
    ON temp_hours_worked.week_beginning = t.week_beginning
        AND temp_hours_worked.employee_id = t.employee_id
        AND temp_hours_worked.company_id=?
WHERE t.company_id = ?;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                                     | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t                 | ref    | company_id    | company_id  | 4       | const                                   | 5566 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e                 | ref    | employee_id   | employee_id | 4       | DBNAME.t.employee_id                    |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d1                | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | DBNAME.e.department                     |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d2                | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | DBNAME.e.sub_department                 |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | DBNAME.e.site_id                        |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e2                | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | DBNAME.e.manager                        |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e3                | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | DBNAME.t.manager_id                     |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temp_hours_worked | ref    | company_id    | company_id  | 4       | const                                   | 5566 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+-------+
```

MySQL version is 5.5.31 running on Centos 6.5 64 bit and the server is 8 core, 4GB RAM with SSD disks. Load average on the box is:

```
load average: 0.24, 0.29, 0.29
```

and free memory shows as:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3880       3067        813          0        177       1065
-/+ buffers/cache:       1825       2055
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

Disk space is OK:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       45G   11G   32G  26% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/usr/tmpDSK    1008M   51M  907M   6% /tmp
```

Output from hdparm -Tt /dev/xvda1

```
 Timing cached reads:   12538 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6297.76 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 826 MB in  3.00 seconds = 275.27 MB/sec
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]


local-infile=0

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid_file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
#sql_mode                      = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
innodb                         = FORCE
#innodb_strict_mode            = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0

max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1456M

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
#log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

The columns being queried/joined are all necessary and cannot be removed and I realise there is no index on quite a few of the columns but as they are only single rows I am not sure it matters - is there anything else I can do to speed this query up?

Comment: Indexes really matter. Did you try to add the missing ones ? For a join to be efficient an index is necessary.

Comment: Btw you say the server has 8GB RAM but the mem output shows slightly less than 4GB. Accidentally running 32-bit after all or misconfigured VM?

Comment: Typo on my part..... It is 4GB RAM

Comment: Is my interpretation right, that your example returned nearly 5566 of rows? And how did you measure the time? Was it like this?: I have a website and waited until my application server returned those results (whereby it does nothing else than writing the results to concole)? In that case: Are you absolutely sure, that your client is not the bottleneck, when it comes to presentation? What happens if you attach a "limit 100" to your statement?

Comment: No I went into the MySQL client and ran it from the command line - I also ran it using limits and the performance difference is pretty linear. I don't recall the exact numbers but I did it 100, 500, 1000, 2500 etc and it was roughly the same time as the relevant percentage of the total rows

Answer (score 3):

This query should never, ever be that slow on those hardware specs. The `explain` output indicates that all joined fields use pretty optimal indexes, and only scans a mere 5566 rows. The only index improvement could be a combined index on `temp_hours_worked` on fields `week_beginning, employee_id, company_id` but that's never going to be be much of a difference. There aren't even any filesorts or temp tables according to the explain output.

I suspect you're either running into locking issues (the load you show is low, but doesn't tell how many simultaneous queries are running on these same tables) or your MySQL is incredibly underpowered by config (using the default `tiny.config` settings or comparable).

Things to check:

- Use `hdparm -Tt /dev/sdX` to test drive performance - the SSD disks or RAID array may be borked
- Check your performance settings. Don't hesitate to put all `buffer` settings in `my.cnf` at least at twice their current value, you have RAM to spare. A few may warrant extremely higher settings. A script like [MySQLTuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) may be of help with this.

Also check whether the issue is reproducable on another server.

A good beginning to up MySQL buffer values is adding this bit to your `my.cnf`:

```
key_buffer = 768M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
query_cache_size = 128M
thread_concurrency = 16
table_open_cache = 2048
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
```

You can review current values in phpMyAdmin (server -> variables).

Comment: Added the output from hdparm as well as the contents of my.cnf in my original post

Comment: Made the changes, still around 30 - 35 seconds to complete at the command line

Comment: Also MySQLTuner is warning Maximum possible memory usage: 8.4G (222% of installed RAM)

Comment: Yeah well at first you said there was 8GB of RAM - 4GB is slightly on the smallish side for an octacore server depending on what you want to do. I also just noticed your swap area is far too small - it should be at least 1.5 times the physical RAM amount of the server, preferably 2. Currently you have 25% which actively impedes OS performance. This could actually present you with performance problems, you should **never** try to 'save' on swap space.